# AppWidget Screen Orientation

Tags: android, android-widget

Here is my question. I have an appwidget which works perfectly in a portrait screen orientation. However, When i changed my screen orientation to landscape my appWidget's width and height changing automatically by the home screen launcher and the problem is in landscape mode my widget's height is not set properly by the homescreen launcher.
So, I need to detect is screen orientation changed and re-size my appwidget. I've googled it but still i don't have any idea how can i do that. If it was an activity it was simple but it's not. I'll be gratefull if anyone has idea about this.

Comment: In your layout.xml design view, there is a view that aloows you to preview your layout in landscape.

Comment: Thanks, i know that feature, but i didn't ask about that. I have asked how can i change my appwidget's layout size in run-time, since i cannot specify both landspace and portrait sizes in my config.xml file.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's what you want, but you can try to make 2 xml config files for your widget. "res/xml-land" and res/xml" and define there a different minSize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the screen orientation changes your AppWidgetProvider onUpdate method gets called. You can use the following function to get if you are in portrait or landscape mode and then update your remote views based on that.

```
private static boolean isPortrait (Context cx) {
Display d = ((WindowManager) cx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

if (d.getWidth() == d.getHeight()) {
    return false;
} else if (d.getWidth() < d.getHeight()) {
    return true;    
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define bools.xml in both values-port and values-land

   In values-port/bools.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <bool name="portrait">true</bool>
   </resources>
   ```

   In values-land/bools.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <bool name="portrait">false</bool>
   </resources>
   ```
2. Get boolean by Context.getResources() in code

   ```
   private static boolean isPortrait(Context context) {
       return context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait);
   }
   ```